Is it possible to count distinct with multiple conditions using MS Excel 2010?
A company has 3 zones, each zone has a specific number of customers. I have a task to count the distinct number of customers on 2 dates: 1/1/2023 and 31/10/2023 for different zones.
Below is the raw data



Customer_ID (number)
Zone
Process_date (number)
Amount




123
Z1
20221231
3


325
Z2
20231031
2


123
Z1
20221231
1


635
Z3
20221231
1



Expected result




Zone
Number of customer on 1/1/2023
Number of customer on 1/1/2023




Z1
1
0


Z2
0
1


Z3
1
0



My attempts were below but none of them gave me correct results. Please help.
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($M$2:$M$9097=20221231,$B$2:$B$9097),IF($K$2:$K$9097="Z1",'Raw Data'!$B$2:$B$9097))>0,1))

=SUMPRODUCT(IF(($M$2:$M$9097="20221231")*($K$2:$K$9097="Z1"),1/COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$9097,$B$2:$B$9097,$M$2:$M$9097,20221231,$K$2:$K$9097,"Z1"),0))


Why not simply use a pivot table?

Because other than this request, I also have to extract the amount from different times (31/12/2022 and 31/10/2023), the fluctuation of the amount between those amounts, the avg amount in 10 months (all in diff zones). So I don't know how to do a pivot table for all those requests. Do you have any suggestions?

It's a simply SUMPRODUCT formula but why not just use a pivot table?
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$5=B$8)*($B$2:$B$5=$A9)*($D$2:$D$5>0))

So you don't want the number of customers but just the indication if any customer was an at any location?
=(SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$5=B$8)*($B$2:$B$5=$A9)*($D$2:$D$5>0))>0)*1



Thanks for the answer. Sorry, there was a typo in my expected result. It should be 1 customer only in Zone 1 on 31/12/2022. I edited it. Can you pls take a look?

=(SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$5=B$8)($B$2:$B$5=$A9)($D$2:$D$5>0))>0)*1

Sorry for being not so clear. I want a distinct number of customers, which means if 1 customer (123) bought 2 times on 1 day (31/12/2023), I will only count 1 customer.

The formula in cell H29 drag to the right and down.
Leave a blank cell in between Zone names and result (as on screenshot). This ensure that the same formula can be used in all the cells.
Cells H28,I28 are the dates in numbers.
=COUNTIFS($B$29:$B$32,$F29,$C$29:$C$32,"<="&H$28)-SUM($G29:G29)

Modified according to the edited question
This formula requires to SORT the range on column A beforehand.
=COUNT(IF(($F37=$B$37:$B$40)*(H$36>=$C$37:$C$40)*($A$37:$A$40<>$A$36:$A$39),$A$37:$A$40,""))-SUM($G37:G37)


Thanks for the answer. Sorry, there was a typo in my expected result. It should be 1 customer only in Zone 1 on 31/12/2022. I edited it. Can you pls take a look?

Thank you for your answer. I don't know why but I used the above sorting formula and it still gives me the wrong answer (all 0).

Are you sure that the process dates and the customers are really all numbers. Check step -by-step the calculation with Evaluate Formula
